# php add item in recursive multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a string format for pushing an item into a recursive array.

Ex. `CEN_SCH_SET_FUL_INT_FAS` or `CEN_SCH_BUS_FUL_ACC_DIP` or `CEN_SCH_BUS`

What I am trying to do is, insert a specific value ex `CEN_SCH_BUS` will be inserted into a multidimensional array with the keys ex. `$global_array['CEN']['SCH']['BUS'] = "CEN_SCH_BUS"`

and same for the other cases.

I have tried to with,

```
array_walk_recursive($value_toinsert , function($item, $key) {
    $global_array[$key] = $value_toinsert;
});
```

but can't see it to work.

One example insertion of `CEN_SCH_SET_FUL_TEC`, so **CEN_SCH_SET_FUL_TEC** is inserted at `CEN > SCH > SET > FUL`

```
Array
(
    [CEN] => Array
        (
            [SCH] => Array
                (
                    [SET] => Array
                        (
                            [FUL] => CEN_SCH_SET_FUL_TEC
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Note: I want to keep adding the other values in the array. It can be within the existing key indexes or different (kind of a tree). Not just one value.

Comment: What is the result of above function and how it differs to intended outcome?

Comment: Check my edited question.

Comment: To use the dupe: `$path = explode('_', $value); array_pop($path);`

Comment: You just need to convert your string value into an array that matches your requirement (use references to continuously create keys within keys), then merge the result recursively with your target array.

Comment: yes. I need to explode and then use recursive but I can't get it.

Comment: I *might* have an answer (if I understood your problem right) but your question has been marked as a duplicate already. Maybe you can find the solution there

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate. What I want is, keep adding more values in the array. The key might be same and different.